# How to make an image move by clicking on a button with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, timer, move

I need to write a javascript code inside an HTML document that has the following behavior:
When a button is clicked, an image starts moving (if it is not already moving), one pixel to the left per second. When a second button is clicked, the image stops moving and immediately gets repositioned to its original coordinates.

I get everything to work, except for the "Button" that says "START". Right now if I click the image the image moves left 1 pixel per second. However I need to carry that function over to the button called START.

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thank you!!

My code is as follow:

```
<html><head>


<script>

var timerid = null;


function move()
{
document.getElementById('cat').style.right = 
    parseInt(document.getElementById('cat').style.right) + 1 + 'px';    
}

window.onload=function()
{   



document.getElementById('cat').onclick=function(){

    if(timerid == null){
        timerid = setInterval("move()", 10);
    }else{
        clearInterval(timerid);
        timerid = null;
    }
}   


var button2 = document.getElementById('button2');
button2.onclick= reloadPage;

    function reloadPage(){
        window.location.reload();
    }

}


</script>
</head>
<body>

<img id="cat" src="cat.jpg" style="position:absolute;right:5px"/>

<div>
<button id="button1" type="button" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:190px"/>START</button>
<button id="button2" type="button" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:220px"/>STOP & RESET</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Things would be much easier by using jQuery which provides this out of the box with `.animate()`

Comment: Thanks I know! I am not allowed to use Jquery for this:(

Answer (score 1):

change `cat` to `button1`

```
document.getElementById('button1').onclick=function(){
                     //--^^^^^^^^----here
  if(timerid == null){
    timerid = setInterval("move()", 10);
  }else{
    clearInterval(timerid);
    timerid = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: HI Bipen, You seem to be a pretty good javascript coder. Can I ask you to take a look at another piece of code that I am struggling with. This one might be a little of a challenge. I have spend hours on this one and nothing yet.

Please see link:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/15696938/2147761
Your help is much appreciated and I thank yo in advance!!

Comment: @user2147761 ok updated you answer back there check the fiddle out in the answer.. :).. and yes if any of the post helps you, then so should not forget to  accept it as answer....