# Validate HTML input in JS prior to change

Tags: javascript, html, validation

It looks like when an `input` element is initially loaded, its validity is not evaluated right away.  For example, if my HTML looks like this...

```html
<input type="text" value="ABC" minlength="5">
```

In JavaScript it appears that the input is valid and not too short, despite the `value` attribute being set to a length less than 5. For example:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");
console.log(input.validity.valid); // true
console.log(input.validity.tooShort); // false
```

Only when the user makes a change in the input can we get a true reckoning of the input's validity.

Is there any way to force the input to evaluate its actual validity on load, even if the user has not yet touched the input?

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/t5afujkn/3/

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason is your default value is not checked from `<input>` directly at load as it probably does not trigger a check for the default values.

You can add another check condition in your `js` as below:

```
{
    const displayObj = {
       valid: input.validity.valid,
       tooShort: input.validity.tooShort
    };
    if (input.value.length < 5) {
       displayObj.valid = false;
       displayObj.tooShort = true;
       document.querySelector("p").textContent = JSON.stringify(displayObj);
    }
}
```

or maybe you can also try to put the `if` condition somewhere outside the button call.

Also I did an update in JSFiddle; not sure if you can see it: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lhp96ct/6/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is just a simple example to illustrate the challenge I'm facing with a complex implementation that leverages HTML5 form validation. I'm not really interested in doing a complete rewrite of that functionality.

Comment: Hey, so your input is inside a form, right? do you use jquery in your project or just vanilla js?

Comment: The `input` isn't inside a form. Putting it inside one in my jsfiddle example doesn't seem to make a difference in behavior. I am using vanilla JS.

Comment: Yes I know you dont have a form, but there are ways in javascript to force the from to validate on load: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696938/form-validation-with-javascript-using-window-onload.
Unfortunately, I am not aware of any method to do that with only `html5` alone. Usually the `inputs` are used inside a form and user usually submit a form. Then the `html5` validation takes place (I think this was the main design goal of having validation on input elements as to be checked when submitting a form). I am sorry, hopefuly someone else can help.

Comment: Also found this article: https://riptutorial.com/html/example/2259/input-validation stating that "The validation only occurs when attempting to submit the form, so all restricted inputs must be inside a form in order for validation to occur (unless you're using JavaScript). Keep in mind that inputs which are disabled or read-only will not trigger validation."

Comment: HTML5 validation properties like `minlength` work when the user interacts with the input element by changing the value. Based on testing, it's clear that this happens with or without a `<form>` element or a submit event, so I'm fairly certain that piece is irrelevant. Possibly the answer is that there is no way to force validation prior to user interaction -- I am still hoping for someone to offer a definitive answer on that.